# Can I scrape away bubbled concrete waterproofer and reapply?

Tags: basement-refinishing

Recently bought a house with painted basement walls, painted with Drylok. They look good except this one corner that has some small peeling, bubbles, and efflorescence coming through in form of small yellow bubbles. I am looking for suggestions on how to make it look nicer and prevent any issues.

I am thinking I could just sand, peel off the efflorescence/peeling paint and then add another coat of Drylok.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Attaching pictures to show you what I'm referring to

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And this is why they tell you that the practicality of waterproofing from the inside is low.

Answer (score 2):

You could try cleaning it off and reapplying, preferably during a dry spell, and using the thicker "waterproofer" product if that wasn't what was used in the first place.

But your odds of success are limited. The physics are against any interior barrier, because the water pressure is trying to peel it off the wall, and usually succeeds. You either need to get a barrier on the outside, or remove the water pressure on the outside, both of which take considerably more effort and digging than having another go at sealing the inside, even though it's expected to fail.

Of course, if there are basic things wrong like "ground does not slope away from the house" or "water from roof is not taken away from the house" they can be addressed with some fairly basic exterior work, and if they are enough, great. Otherwise you need to dig down and add exterior drainage, and while doing that you might as well apply an exterior membrane, which is pushed onto the wall harder by water pressure, so it tends to work.

Comment: can you elaborate on cleaning it off and reapplying, i'm thinking just wirebrush and another coat of drylok?

as for the exterior, the previous owner did do some digging and re-routed water, not sure if this is just left over moisture or what not, but land is graded correctly and what not

Comment: You might want to acid etch after wire brushing and before reapplying. I'd guess that was a "nice fresh coat of drylok to make the basement look good for the sale" done with minimal preparation. "So white, so clean, so painted right over the receptacle" it looks like. If that's a GFCI, test it. Depending what you see, a degreaser/detergent (TSP) might also be beneficial, particularly if there's an oil-burning appliance in the basement.

Comment: do you mean an acid etch as just water/vinegar mix? I really don't want to get my hands full of more than I need, I would be comfortable wire brushing some, using vinegar, drying it, and re dry-loking?

Comment: The usual/default etch for paint prep on concrete is muriatic (hydrochloric) acid. I guess vinegar would be better than nothing, but it has terrible fumes. Citric acid is stronger than vinegar but does not fume so much, weaker than muriatic.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know if i'd be comfortable with that at all when it seems what i'm trying to solve isn't really a issue, mostly a cosmetic one

Any other recommendation for me if I wanted to avoid using that?

Comment: See many past answers about waterproofing basements